# java web start problem with sign file

Tags: java, java-web-start

```
Unsigned application requesting unrestricted access to system
Unsigned resource: http://*/kis/adfjars/sqlj/lib/runtime12.jar
```

Exception:

```
    <jar href="http://*/kis/adfjars/jlib/oracle-el.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://*/kis/adfjars/jlib/share.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://*/kis/adfjars/lib/dms.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://*/kis/adfjars/lib/xmlparserv2.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://*/kis/adfjars/ord/jlib/ordim.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://*/kis/adfjars/sqlj/lib/runtime12.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  </resources>
  <library-desc unique-id="null"/>
</jnlp> ]
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.continueLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.handleApplicationDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.handleLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

but when i deploy second time to oc4j then start working. Sometimes work for first time. Any idea why? All other files are signed only this file has problem, but not always.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometime ago i had a problem like this one. In my case the problem was some JARs whose certificates were expired. As soon as i replaced them with a current version everything went ok. My advice  would be to check the certificate expiration date from runtime12.jar. Hope this helps.

Bye.

***Paul Manjarres***

Comment: Incidentally, the newest version of oc4j is 10.1.3.5, which may include said drivers.